# Generator not working properly

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm trying to create a generator that spits out ores every couple of seconds.

The problem is that the sign changes to a generator, but it does not spit out ores.

```
   @EventHandler
   public void onSignChange(SignChangeEvent e) {
           if (e.getLine(0).equalsIgnoreCase("DGEN")) {
                   e.setLine(0, "§0§lGENERATOR");
                   e.setLine(1, "§bDiamond");
                   e.setLine(2, "§0Level 1");
           }
   }

   @EventHandler
   public void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
           if (!(e.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK)) return;
           if((e.getClickedBlock().getType() == Material.SIGN_POST) || (e.getClickedBlock().getType() == Material.WALL_SIGN)){
                Sign s = (Sign) e.getClickedBlock().getState();
                   if (s.getLine(1).equalsIgnoreCase("§0§lGENERATOR")) {
                       e.getPlayer().getWorld().dropItemNaturally(e.getPlayer().getLocation(), new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_ORE, 1));
                           e.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Diamond Gen works!");
                   }
           }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the line `1` (the second line) as `"§bDiamond"`:

```
e.setLine(1, "§bDiamond");
```

So this statement:

```
if (s.getLine(1).equalsIgnoreCase("§0§lGENERATOR")) { [...] }
```

will never be `true`, since line `1` has a value of `"§bDiamond"`.

Comment: I tried this, still it doesnt work. Now when i go in game and write DGEN on a sign, the Signchange does not happen

Comment: Have you tried cancelling the even before setting the lines? Just a guess.